# Google Adscense with Amazon S3 hosted site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, adsense

I have setup my first website on Amazon S3 successfully, but I get 403 error from Google Adsense.

I did following to fix the problem.

1. I ensured to copy the adsense code as it is with out error.
2. I have added my domain name in my google account and verified it.
3. I cannot reach out to my amazon tech support since I am still under free account.

But no luck.

Please let me know if I need to do any other action to get Adsense working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since domains of your S3 bucket and adnsense endpoints are different browser will not allow it. You will have it turn on CORS for your S3 bucket. Read -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html